# extracting data from a string and store in a dictionary python3x

Tags: python, string, dictionary, data-structures

I have the following string

```
s='''
gulf energy 8"x3" drilling jar (6"5/8 reg box x pin) received 01/06/2019   ** schlumberger 6"1/2 drilling jar
** gulf energy 8"x3" drilling jar (6"5/8 reg box x pin) received 01/06/2019   ** schlumberger 6"1/2 drilling jar
** gulf energy 8"x3" drilling jar (6"5/8 reg box x pin) received 01/06/2019   ** schlumberger 6"1/2 drilling jar
'''
```

and the following dictionary

```
G_Energy = {'4"3/4': 0, '6"': 0, '6"1/2': 0, '8"': 0, '8"1/4': 0}
```

I want to search the string and if any of the sizes match any of the keys of dictionary add 1 to the key's value 
how will I do that keep in mind I am looking for an eloquent solution i have like a large amount of data

Comment: Is pythons [count()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_count.htm) method what you want?

Comment: its the condition to septate the data not just the method count is what I am after because i applied count and it took all the values not just the ones i wanted i need to construct an argument that checks if a word in a line then count the numbers in that line

Answer (score 0):

Use Python's [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html?highlight=re%20compile#re.compile) to find the matches in the string, and a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to make the counting easier:

```py
s='''
gulf energy 8"x3" drilling jar (6"5/8 reg box x pin) received 01/06/2019   ** schlumberger 6"1/2 drilling jar
** gulf energy 8"x3" drilling jar (6"5/8 reg box x pin) received 01/06/2019   ** schlumberger 6"1/2 drilling jar
** gulf energy 8"x3" drilling jar (6"5/8 reg box x pin) received 01/06/2019   ** schlumberger 6"1/2 drilling jar
'''

import re
import collections

# collections.Counter uses default keys with values of 0
count = collections.Counter()

# specify whatever regex you need
RE = re.compile(r'[0-9]+"([0-9]+/[0-9]+)?')

# for each match, add 1 to the counter
for f in RE.finditer(s):
    dimension = f.string[slice(*f.span())]
    count[dimension] += 1

print(count)
```

Outputs

```
Counter({'8"': 3, '3"': 3, '6"5/8': 3, '6"1/2': 3})
```

If you really want to limit which sizes you have in the final dict, filter them out later:

```py
keep_dimensions = set(('4"3/4', '6"', '6"1/2', '8"', '8"1/4'))
G_Energy = {k:count[k] for k in keep_dimensions}
```

gives

```
{'6"': 0, '6"1/2': 3, '4"3/4': 0, '8"1/4': 0, '8"': 3}
```